# find file in hadoop filesystem

Tags: file, hadoop, filesystems

Is there a way to locate a specific file in hadoop?

I know, that I can use this:
`hadoop fs -find /some_directory`

But, is there a command like this: `hadoop locate some_file_name`?

Comment: I answered in another post proposing a software to index all file names in hdfs named Schemaindex. The software is built on python and adminlte(js). This index software also leverage inotify feature from HDFS to monitor hdfs in real time. The project is here on github: schemaindex (https://github.com/qiyangduan/schemaindex) If anyone wants to try it, you can install it by:
$ pip install schemaindex
$schemaindex runserver
Then you can create a data source and “reflect” the data source. Disclaimer: I am the auther and eager for someone to try it. You can try it and let me know bugs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are looking for equivalent of **locate** Linux command than such option does not exist in Hadoop. But if you are looking for the way of how to find specific file you can use **name** parameter of **fs -find** command for this:

```
hadoop fs -find /some_directory -name some_file_name
```

If you are looking for the actual location of hdfs file in your local file system you can use **fsck** command for this:

```
hdfs fsck /some_directory/some_file_name -files -blocks -locations
```

Comment: Thank you. First variant is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Any idea how to use what the `hadoop fs -find` docs refer to as an `expression`?  From the docs: `-find <path> ... <expression> ... :
  Finds all files that match the specified expression and
  applies selected actions to them. If no <path> is specified
  then defaults to the current working directory. If no
  expression is specified then defaults to -print.`  I would like to use `find` to identify things in `/path1` but ignore `/path1/path2`.  I know I could `grep -v path2` but I would prefer not to traverse that directory at all.

Comment: @user9074332 should be similar to generic find linux command I suppose - https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ufind.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can list the directories and grep the result:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /anyDirectory/* | grep theFileNameISearch
```